# LINUX / C++ Remove strings in first file from the second file

Tags: c++, linux, algorithm

I am trying to compare two files of strings and remove everything that is in file 1 from file 2 if its there and save it in a third output file. I was going to write a c++ program for this but best i could come up with was O(N^2), is there any commands in Linux to do this? if not what is the most efficient way to do it with c++ ? these files have up to 1 billion strings in one and 10 million in another so O(N^2) is extremely inefficient

ex f1
hello
josh 
cory
sam
don

f2 
jack
josh
joey
sam
neda
etc

outputfile:
jack
joey
neda
etc

to be clear I am NOT trying to merge them then remove duplicates, i only want duplicates of strings in file 1 removed from file 2. 
thanks

Comment: If you have a billion strings in a file, perhaps text files are not the best way to store this information.

Comment: what format are you recommending ? the program that is going to use these pretty much needs txt files. so i have little room.

Answer (score 3):

`fgrep` is handy for this: it will grep one file for a set of fixed strings.

`fgrep -f f1 -v f2` will print out all lines in `f2` that are not found in `f1`.

Comment: so if i just add > fil3 that would output that into this file instead of stdout ? cause i don't want to see millions of strings pop on terminal!

Comment: for some reason this doesn't seem to work properly. after doing this,with f1 having 500000 strings and f2 having 800000 the output file only has 1400 strings. that just doesnt add up right, if f2 contain all of f1 it would still have about 300000 strings left

Comment: Not if some of the strings in f1 appear multiple times.

Comment: @qwrrty but i have already removed duplicates within each file! so that can't be possible!

Comment: @Tangleman: to make it work properly you could try `-w` or `-x` options (match whole word or whole line).

Comment: @EvgenyKluev is it -w or -x ?! each one gives me different result! both seem reasonable one is near 800k and other about 500k

Comment: @EvgenyKluev these files are one string per line and sorted. I am really beyond confused, because using C++ STL List,  when I sort, merge then unique (remove duplicates) i find that there are 270000 duplicates between these two files. using this above command with -w or -x does not remove that many strings. any ideas?

Comment: @Tangleman: I cannot explain this. Just a guess: if some of your strings are multi-word, `-x` should give proper result; if some of them contain leading/trailing spaces, `-w` is the right way; if both multi-word and trailing spaces, you could try to preprocess them with `sed` to strip trailing spaces, then use `-x` option.

Answer (score 1):

You can solve this task by using the Aho-Corasick string matching algorithm. It is used for multiple-keyword search across text and it's time complexity is linear.

There are some C++ implementations of this algorithm on the net. For example [this](http://www.komodia.com/aho-corasick).

In addition, there is a nice-looking [python library](https://hkn.eecs.berkeley.edu/~dyoo/python/ahocorasick/) for this.

However, I'm not sure if the memory complexity is OK when using those sources/libraries. You may have to read the input from the first file in chunks (as it may have billions of characters).

Comment: Aho-Corasick is strikes me as overkill for this.

Comment: @RichardPlunkett Well, it depends. If you only have to match whole strings, then a simple hash table would do it. However, if a single text word may contain multiple overlapping pattern words (as "import", "port" and "ant" in "important"), then Aho-Corasick is the solution. When I read the question, I immediately related multiple string matching and "inefficient O(n^2)" with Aho-Corasick. I think it's a suitable solution as one can simply use the library that implements it. Additionally, it is good to be aware about that powerful algorithm.

Comment: Well these are huge dictionaries of words, one string per line, there will certainly be overlapping patter because its such a huge list. i will look into this algorithm, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You could code a C++ (or Ocaml) program which reads all the words of the first file and store them in a set of strings (using `std::set<std::string>` in C++, or `module SS = Set.Make(String);;` in Ocaml). Filling that set should be *O(n log n)* complexity (where *n* is the number of words, i.e. the cardinal of the set). Testing that a file of *m* words each word belongs (or not) to that set is *O (m log n)*

Sets are implemented as balanced trees with a logarithmic membership test time.

However, you should probably have used some data base systems to store (and fill) the data. (e.g. PostGreSQL, MariaDB, MongoDB, CouchDB, ....)